# Input button script conflicting with other buttons - How to make unique?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, input, click

I have many buttons in one form.  I made one script for a few particular buttons and now my other buttons are not working correctly.

Is it possible to make my button script unique for only the designated butons avoiding conflict with other buttons? It appears "input[type='button']" applies to all buttons in the form *when I only want it to apply to a few in the script*.

Here is the script I wish to modify to only work for a few particular buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(function() {
      var $buttons = $("input[type='button']");
      $buttons.click(function() {

      $(this).parent().siblings('.bx, #bxGender .gender').css({'background':'#2F2F2F','color':'#fff'});
    $buttons.not(this).removeClass('button-toggle-on');
    $(this).toggleClass('button-toggle-on').attr('style','');

    var varval = '';
    if ($(this).hasClass('button-toggle-on')) {
        varval = $(this).hasClass('gnF') ? 'Female' : 'Male';
        $(this).siblings('input[type="button"]').css('background-position','0 -180px');
    }
    else {
          $(this).siblings('input[type="button"]').attr('style','');
       $(this).parent().siblings('.bx').attr('style','');
    }
    $("#gender").val(varval);
 });});
 });



 <input type="button" class="gnM" >
 <input type="button" class="gnF">
 <input class="req-string gender" id="gender" name="gender">
```

Comment: You are correct that `input[type='button']` will select all buttons.  You need to narrow your selection using jQuery selectors, such as selecting by class, by id, by attributes, etc.

Comment: You can add classes to groups of buttons and use the "." selector, ex. $(".group1").click(function()...

Comment: Would there be an example I could see, because I'm still a novice at scripting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? Here's an example of using classes to only affect certain elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $(".special-button").click(function() {

            $(this).parent().siblings('.bx, #bxGender.gender').css({'background':'#2F2F2F','color':'#fff'});
            $(this).siblings('.special-button').removeClass('button-toggle-on');
            $(this).toggleClass('button-toggle-on').attr('style','');

            var varval = '';
            if ($(this).hasClass('button-toggle-on')) {
                varval = $(this).hasClass('gnF') ? 'Female' : 'Male';
                $(this).siblings('.special-button').css('background-position','0 -180px');
            }
            else {
                $(this).siblings('.special-button').attr('style','');
                $(this).parent().siblings('.bx').attr('style','');
            }
            $("#gender").val(varval);
        });
    });
});

 <input type="button" class="gnM special-button" >
 <input type="button" class="gnF special-button">
 <input class="req-string gender" id="gender" name="gender">
```

Comment: This helped me understand.  Learned something new.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ 
You can use dom element's id, class, name & many others to select elements using jquery.

So, to narrow down your selection to the buttons you wish better use same class attribute

Ex:

HTML:

```
<input type='button' class='mine' value='hai' />
<input type='button' class='not-mine' value='hai' />
<input type='button' class='not-mine' value='hai' />
<input type='button' class='mine' value='hai' />
```

and then using jquery

`$('.mine').click() or $('.mine').addClass` or any valid jquery function you wish to use

jQuery returns the proper `this` attribute even if there are many dom elements match your selector attribute [here there are 2 buttons with same class].

A complete example:
http://jsfiddle.net/AEkbh/2/

Answer (score 0):

Or if you still want to contain all your button handlers in one method but target specific ones:

```
$( document ).ready( function(){
  $( "input[type='button']" ).click( function( e ){
    var $this = $( this );
    switch( true ){
      case $this.hasClassName( "special-button" ):
        //do some stuff
      break;
      case $this.attr("name") === "gender":
        //do something else
      break;
      default:
        //catch all other cases
     }
   });
 });
```

So many ways to skin a javascript cat